# How to increase product quantity if a product is already exist in session

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am using the below code and want to increase the quantity in session array but its not working

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['quote']))
{

$prdata=$_SESSION['quote'];
}

$product_id = $data['id'];
$product_image = $data['image'];
$product_name = $data['pname'];
$product_quantity = $data['quantity'];
$product_price = $data['price'];

foreach ($_SESSION["quote"] as $cart_itm){         
         if($cart_itm['product_id'] == $product_id){ //the item exist in array

    $newdat = array('product_id' => $product_id,'quantity'=>$product_quantity,'price'=>$product_price,'name'=>$product_name,'image'=>$product_image); 
    $found = true;

}else{

    $newdat = array('product_id' => $product_id,'quantity'=>$product_quantity,'price'=>$product_price,'name'=>$product_name,'image'=>$product_image); 

}
```

Comment: What do mean by "not working"? What do you expect? What happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put there `product_id` etc. again, change just amount. Your code will be shorter, clearer and you avoid to other possible typos, etc.

```
if($cart_itm['product_id'] == $product_id) {
    $cart_itm['quantity'] += $product_quantity; // expect in $product_quantity is the amount you want to add to the current one
    // it's a shorter variant of $cart_itm['quantity'] = $cart_itm['quantity'] + $product_quantity; 
}
```

Comment: Don`t forget that, visitor need to empty cart and decrease product amo too. I sugest create ajax class where is increse() delete_cart() and decrease() functions.

Comment: @KārlisMillers: irrelevant. We don't know where OP took the variable, it can be from the detail page, for example. The other thing is, that `+= -1` decrease the amount correctly.

Comment: Ofcourse. Well then update() and delete_cart() will be fine. Store values in session and on succesful ajax update refress products count in cart etc..

Comment: Also don`t need forget that you can`t decrease quantity who is lower than 0

Comment: @KārlisMillers: there is no reason why to store 0-pcs products in cart. When product has amount = 0, it has to be removed from cart. It's for a set of conditions, OP only wanted to know how to add any amount to the existing one.